# TYPO3 VHS only get image Tag

Tags: typo3, view-helpers

I want to get only the `img` tag not the whole `cObject`. This is what I´ve done:

```html
<v:content.render pageUid="{this.uid}" column="5" as="tcolsid">
    <f:debug>{tcolsid.0}</f:debug>
    <f:format.raw>{tcolsid.0}</f:format.raw>
</v:content.render>
```

This is what I get:

```html
<div id="c3" class="frame frame-default frame-type-image frame-layout-0">
    <div class="ce-image ce-center ce-above">
        <div class="ce-gallery" data-ce-columns="1" data-ce-images="1">
            <div class="ce-outer">
                <div class="ce-inner">
                    <div class="ce-row">
                        <div class="ce-column">
                            <figure class="image">
                                <img class="image-embed-item" src="fileadmin/user_upload/cappucino.jpg" width="1500" height="1101" alt=""/>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i only want to get the img tag:

```html
<img class="image-embed-item" src="fileadmin/user_upload/cappucino.jpg" width="1500" height="1101" alt=""/>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Using proper formatting in code samples helps both: us to understand your problem and you... to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```html
<v:content.render pageUid="23" column="0" as="records" render="false">
<f:for each="{records}" as="record">
    {v:resource.record.fal(table: 'tt_content', field: 'image', uid: '{record.uid}')
        -> v:iterator.first()
        -> v:variable.set(name: 'image')}
    <f:if condition="{image}">
        <v:media.image
            alt="{f:if(condition: '{image.alternative}', then: '{image.alternative}', else: '{data.header}')}"
            class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" crop="{image.crop}" src="{image.uid}" 
            srcsetDefault="1024" treatIdAsReference="1" />
    </f:if>
</f:for>
</v:content.render>
```

Comment: I suggest using `v:content.get` which is the equivalent of `v:content.render` with `render="0"`, `v:content.get` does not need the `render` argument and is more logical when another developer reads the template. You also should not use the string `false` in boolean properties, using 0 or 1 is safer/faster.